# registerContentObserver

Tags: android, android-contentresolver

I want to get callback about any audio notify.
I create observer:

```
getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, false, new MyContentObserver(_handler) { ...
```

I get onChange each time, then add or remove some song.

But I don't understood another: I copy to device some file (test.log). I don't get onChange after copy file. But If I remove this file I get onChange. But why?

Answer (score 1):

Within your content provider you can define for which action a notification should be sent. Here is an example for the `delete()` action.

```
@Override
public int delete(Uri uri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
    final SQLiteDatabase db = mOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    switch (sUriMatcher.match(uri)) {
        case POSTS: {
            int rowCount = db.delete(DatabaseProperties.TABLE_NAME_POSTS, selection, selectionArgs);
            getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
            return rowCount;
        }
        default: {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Unknown URI: " + uri);
        }
    }
}
```

The command you probably miss, is `notifyChange()`.